# MySQL query trying not to use SELECT IN

Tags: mysql, join

I have a big query like this:

```
SELECT Id , Nuser FROM t_logs 

WHERE Nuser IN 
(

SELECT t_user.kit.idUser
FROM t_kit 
RIGHT JOIN t_user_kit ON t_user_kit.Nkit = t_kit.Nkit 
LEFT JOIN t_user_master ON t_user_master.Nmaster = t_user_kit.idUser
WHERE Tkit='BOX1'

)
```

The subquery returns a list of users, and then I get from t_log all the rows with any of those users (IN).

But I've heard SELECT IN performance is not good, and I don't know how to create this query in an other way. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with the subquery:

```
SELECT Id, Nuser
FROM t_logs AS l
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT uk.idUser
      FROM t_kit AS k
      RIGHT JOIN t_user_kit AS uk ON uk.nKit = k.nKit
      LEFT JOIN t_user_master AS um ON um.nMaster = uk.idUser
      WHERE tKit = 'BOX1') AS k ON l.nUser = k.idUser
```

`DISTINCT` in the subquery prevents the join from producing duplicate rows if the subquery returns multiple rows with the same `idUser`. If that's not possible, you can remove that modifier.

Comment: Thank you. this worked!. is the use of aliases good for performance? or just to read the code?

Comment: It's just to make the code more readable, it has no effect on performance.